# Unpack nested tuples in python

Tags: python, tuples

I have a nested tuple like `((((), A), B), C)` that I retrieve from a recursive function. I would like to extract the elements in the order `A, B, C`. Is there a smart way to do this in python?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: If you need only those scalar values, change your recursive function to accumulate them without tuple wrapping

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: Create a list when you first start your function, then append an element to the list whenever it's not a tuple; this way they'll be appended in order.

Answer (score 2):

A similar recursive idea to @matszwecja 's, except implemented as a generator using `yield` and `yield from`:

```
t = ((((), "A"), "B"), "C")

def unpacker(it):
    for elem in it:
        if not isinstance(elem, tuple):
            yield elem
        else:
            yield from unpacker(elem)

print(tuple(unpacker(t)))
```

Outputs:

```
('A', 'B', 'C')
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over each element, and call the function on it recursively if it's a tuple, append to result list otherwise.

```
t = ((((), "A"), "B"), "C")

def unpack(t, l = None):
    if l == None:
        l = []
    if isinstance(t, tuple):
        for el in t:
            unpack(el, l)
    else:
        l.append(t)
    return l

print(unpack(t))
```